# Creating File 1c9e:98ff for VKOM 3G Modem

Tags: files

In order to install this i need to first create the above file, and well being new to Ubuntu, I do not know how, a step by step guide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.telewell.fi/files/ohjekirjat/TW-3G_HSPA+_USB_Modem_Ubuntu_Installation_Guide.pdf @takkat

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you need to create a file with additional content (see you installation guide for details).

You can easily do that by opening a text editor, which would be **Gedit** in you default installation. Search for "gedit" or "text editor" in the Dash (press <kbd>Win</kbd> key to open).

Then you can copy & paste the content for this file there to then **save** the file by giving it the name `1c90e:98ff`. Memorize the location (folder or path) you saved it for further installation steps.

To simply create an **empty** file open a terminal and type

```
> 1c90e:98ff
```

This will create an empty file in the current directory (usually `/home/<yourname>/`). This file can then be opened later with an editor to fill it with content.